# Sample from sphere under linear constraints

Tags: distributions, sampling, uniform-distribution

The goal is to sample from a uniform distribution ${\bf x} \sim U({\bf x})\in\mathbb{R}^N$ subject to

1. $\left\|{\bf x}\right\|^2 = \delta$ **(sphere constraint)**,
2. $x_i \in [\min_i,\max_i]$ **(box-constraint on each element)**
3. ${\bf v}^\top\!{\bf x} = \delta$

for a given scalar $\delta > 0$ and ${\bf v}\in\mathbb{R}^N$. What is simplest and most efficient way to do so?

### Update #1

To explain the last constraint consider two points ${\bf y}_1, {\bf y}_2 \in\mathbb{R}^N$. I want to sample a random step ${\bf x}$ such that the distance $d({\bf y}_1, {\bf y}_2 + {\bf x})$ is the same as before, $d({\bf y}_1, {\bf y}_2)$. With L2-distance measure we get the condition

$$\left\|{\bf y}_1 - {\bf y}_2 - {\bf x}\right\|_2^2 = \left\|{\bf y}_1 - {\bf y}_2\right\|_2^2$$

$$\Leftrightarrow 2({\bf y}_1 - {\bf y}_2)^\top{\bf x} = \left\|{\bf x}\right\|_2^2 = \delta$$

and so we get condition 3. for ${\bf v} = 2({\bf y}_1 - {\bf y}_2)$.